# Change column order if in a small device

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a row with two columns using `col-md-6 col-sm-12` each, so if in a small device, each column will use the entire width and force a line break. However I need to change the order of these columns when viewed in a small screen (first column must be displayed after the second).

I tried with the following code, however the first column had its position changed even o desktop.

```
<div id="panel-details" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-sm-push-12">
        <ul class="video-details">
            <li class="video-title">
                Title
            </li>
            <li class="video-author">
                Name
            </li>
            <li class="video-description">
                Description
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-sm-pull-12">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Preview]

Comment: I guess a better solution will be to use flexbox. You can take a look at the examples [over here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: That's what float is for.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to place the *second* column before your first so it appears in that order on smaller viewports then once you're over `768px` the *second* column will move to the right with the first on the left. Also, you need to apply the push/pull classes to **col-md-6**, not **col-sm-6**. Mobile first!

See [Column ordering](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering)

Working Example:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        Second
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6 col-sm-12">
      <ul class="video-details list-unstyled">
        <li class="video-title">
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
            First 1
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="video-author">
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
            First 2
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="video-description">
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
            First 3
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```